# Install Macrium Reflect Free Edition on Windows Server 2008 x64

Tags: backup, partitioning, windows-server-2008

I'm not able to install Macrium Reflect on a Windows Server 2008 (which i'm using as a workstation) :
the installer says : "Incompatible with Windows Server". Whereas, the releases notes said Macrium Reflect is working with Server 2008..

What can I do to install it properly ? Have got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

macrium reflect free is for personal use only, and as such generally refuses to install on server versions - since the assumption is very few folk would run a server for personal use. the 'full' version will however cheerfully do so. This is a 'feature' not a bug. Many free versions of AV software do the same thing.